# What is the best way to fill a slice from an iterator in Rust?

Tags: optimization, iterator, copy, rust, slice

I'm implementing `FromIterator` for `[MyStruct;4]` where `MyStruct` is a small Copy struct. My current implementation is

```
fn from_iter<I: IntoIterator<Item=MyStruct>>(iter: I) -> Self {
    let mut retval = [Default::default();4];

    for (ret, src) in retval.iter_mut().zip(iter) {
        *ret = src;
    }

    retval
}
```

This works just fine, however I'm not sure that the `for` loop is as idiomatic as it could be. Is there perhaps a method like `Slice::fill(iter)` that could accomplish this more cleanly (and perhaps more efficiently)?

Comment: Maybe you can just use plain, old [map](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.map)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loops are OK and they generally optimize very well.

Another solution may be to `collect()` into an [`ArrayVec`](https://crates.io/crates/arrayvec). It avoids having to fill the array with a default value first.